# Grabar lista en excel usando openpyxl sin asignar variables para cada dato

Tags: python, excel, lista, openpyxl

Estoy intentando grabar una lista de números en excel. Necesito convertir la lista a float y agregar los valores. Tengo este código y funciona, pero necesito optimizarlo porque la lista real tiene un montón de valores. Alguna idea de como hacerlo mejor?

```
precios = [1,2,4]

a= float(precios[0])
b= float(precios[1])
c= float(precios[2])

wb = load_workbook(r"path")
ws = wb.worksheets[1]

valores = [
    [a, b,c],
    ]

for i in valores:
  ws.append(i)

wb.save("path")
```

Comment: `valores = [ [float(x) for x in precios] ]`

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, mil gracias!